# Check if there exists a vector that satisfies a set of inequalities but violates another set of inequalities

Tags: linear-programming, algorithms

**Problem**

Given rectangular matrices $A$, $B$ and vectors $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$, how to check if there exists an $\vec{x}$ that satisfies the following conditions?

1. $\vec{x} \succcurlyeq \vec{0}$ is true.
2. $A\vec{x} \succcurlyeq \vec{a}$ is true.
3. $B\vec{x} \succcurlyeq \vec{b}$ is false.

For vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$, $\vec{u} \succcurlyeq \vec{v}$ means:

- The vectors have the same number of elements.
- For all i, the i<sup>th</sup> elements of the vectors satisfy $u_i > v_i$.

I can't use $B\vec{x} \preccurlyeq \vec{b}$ because $\vec{x}$ only have to violate at least 1 inequalities among all inequalities represented by $B\vec{x} \succcurlyeq \vec{b}$.

Each problem has about 100 variables and 150 inequalities. I want to solve at least 10,000 problems per minute on a laptop. All of the problems share a large number of inequalities.

---

**Ideas**

Define two problems:

- $P_{A}$ means $\vec{x} \succcurlyeq \vec{0}$ and $A\vec{x} \succcurlyeq \vec{a}$ are true.
- $P_{B}$ means $\vec{x} \succcurlyeq \vec{0}$ and $B\vec{x} \succcurlyeq \vec{b}$ are true.

If I remember correctly, I think:

- Vectors that satisfies $P_{A}$ are the convex combinations of the vertex set $V_{A}$.

  - The vectors in $V_A$ form a matrix $M_{A}$.
  - The convex combinations form a convex set $S_{A}$.
- Vectors that satisfies $P_{B}$ are the convex combinations of the vertex set $V_{B}$.

  - The vectors in $V_B$ form a matrix $M_{B}$.
  - The convex combinations form a convex set $S_{B}$.
- Intersection of two convex sets is convex.
- Difference of two convex sets is not necessarily convex.

**Idea 2**

- The problem is equivalent to showing if $S_{A}$ is not a subset of $S_{B}$.
- I think the problem is also equivalent to showing if there exists a vertex $\vec{\alpha} \in V_A$ such that $\vec{\alpha}$ is not a convex combination of $V_B$. That means $M_{B}\vec{u} = \vec{\alpha}$ either has no solution or $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{1} \ne 1$.

I don't know how to find the vertexes. And there are potentially so many vertexes.

**Idea 3**

- Start from an old problem without such a $\vec{x}$
- By comparing the new $P_{B}$ and old $P_{B}$, we can identify the new cuts.
- Invert the comparison in the new cuts. ($\ge$ to $\le$).
- Check if each new inverted cut is compatible with the new $P_{A}$.

  - For each inverted new cut, add the inverted new cut to the new $P_A$. If simplex algorithm says the combined problem is feasible, the new inverted cut is compatible with the new $P_A$.
- The new problem has such a $\vec{x}$ if and only if we find a new inverted cut that is incompatible with the new $P_{A}$.

That would be at most 60 runs of simplex per problem.
The method caches the inequalities instead of the vertices.

I don't need the solution and only need to know if the new inverted cut is compatible with the existing cuts. Is there a faster way to get this?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your notation means $u_i \ge v_i$ rather than $u_i > v_i$. Strict inequalities are somewhat problematic here.

First comment: Regardless of how you end up modeling this, I would be very surprised if you could solve 10,000 instances per minute on a laptop, even if consecutive instances have considerable commonality.

Second comment: For statement 3 to be false, there must be an index $i$ such that $B^{(i)} x < b_i$ (where $B^{(i)}$ denotes the $i$-th row of $B$. In practice, strict inequalities likely cannot be handled (especially if you end up solving an optimization problem), so you will almost certainly have to introduce a tolerance $\epsilon > 0$ and change statement 3 to $B^{(i)}x \le b_i - \epsilon$ for some $i$.

Third comment: Unless you know that the feasible regions of $P_A$ and $P_B$ are bounded, the correct statement is that a point in either one is the sum of a convex combination of vertices and nonnegative combination of rays (extreme directions).

Fourth comment: Identifying all vertices (and rays) of a polyhedron can be computationally expensive ... plus, for condition 3, you would need to show that the chosen $x$ cannot be expressed in terms of vertices and rays, which would be tricky.

Last comment: You can model this as a mixed integer linear program (though I'd be even more certain that 10K solutions per minute would be off the table). Introduce a binary variable $y_i$ with the same dimension as the number of rows in $B$. The feasible region for your problem is defined by $$x\ge 0$$ $$Ax\ge a$$ $$B^{(i)}x \le b_i -\epsilon + M_i y_i \quad \forall i$$and $$\sum_i y_i \ge 1.$$ $M_i$ is a "large enough" positive constant for each $i$. The objective function can be pretty much anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot. $P_{A}$ and $P_{B}$ are always bounded.